# Can you alter standard JMeter XML output in your plugin?

Tags: java, xml, logging, jmeter, output

I made a custom SampleResult and have overriden the response data in the plugin.
I used "JMeterUtils.setProperty(OUTPUT_FORMAT_PROP, XML);" to set the XML output in runtime. The problem is that when I run JMeter in non gui mode and run the tests, the output is in a format I don't need. (I don't want to save the saveconfig settings etc, only my response data). I also made a complete custom logging system for the tests, which is way more detailed than the standard logging and more in the specific way I want to log.

Although setting the save response data on true, it does not print it and the tag in the output is empty. Also, I think I found a few bugs in JMeter itself for writing to XML, sometimes it doesn't close it's tags like the 'label' tag.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible, as property jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format is used in a static block on load of SampleSaveConfiguration.

So switch format just put in user.properties:

- jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml

If you use 2.13 version, there are no such bugs and if so you should open a bugzilla.
I suspect issue is due to your custom code.

Comment: That's too bad, Then I'll just try to implement my own XML logging in response data or message.
Yes I am using 2.13, if you say it's because of my code, I'll investigate what's going wrong. Although I get no errors when running a Simple Data Writer in GUI mode, so I don't really know why it does not close certain tags...

Comment: Also, I want to set everything like <time>false</time>, but when I do this in my code, with the properties, it doesn't work. Is there a specific place or time this needs to be set?

Comment: Okay, I managed to do something writing my response message. But now the xml shows as : &lt;/logDetail&gt;&#xd; instead of <logDetail>
EDIT: Using an ObjectOutputStream, that's the problem, because the outputstream converts the "<" to &lt;

Comment: unfortunately I cannot help you unless I see your code and understand why exactly you want to do this.